# Eclipse can't understand i edited a class

Tags: java, eclipse

i have a weird problem.
I copied a java class from a web application on a computer to a web application on another computer.

Then I edited the parameters of a method in a class, but when i run my webapp eclipse  gives me this error:

```
The method getContenutoMultimediale(String, String, String)
 in the type GestioneImmagineVideo 
is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, String, int, int)
```

But my method GestioneImmagineVideo  now has 5 parameters, and not 3.
Eclipse cant' understand that i edited that method.

How can i 'refresh' eclipse?
I tried with the refresh (f5) on my project, on my java resources/src folder, i restarted ecplipse and windows.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try cleaning and rebuilding ?  Or close the project and then open it again.

Comment: I closed  and opened it one million times.
How can i clean and rebuild it? I cant' find that features when i click on the project with the right mouse button

Comment: Select the project, go to the `Project` menu (in the menu bar, not in the right-click contextual menu) and select `Clean...`. It will even prompt you if you want to immediately rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

it's not an eclipse problem, you have to redeploy your web application.What server are you using?
remove the webapp from the server, start it and redeploy it again and restart it

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse obviously does not find your new version of the class. To find out which version it uses, try to place the cursor on `getContenutoMultimediale` and press *F3*. Then Eclipse should open the class that it uses for the method...